# Spresense SDK にspresense/sdk/bspが存在しない

Tags: spresense

[Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html)に沿ってチュートリアルを進めています．

開発環境:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
VSCode Ver. 1.61.2 (現時点最新)
Spresense SDK Ver. 2.3.0 (現時点最新)

VSCodeのIncludePassにおいてエラーがありました．

```
/home/trl/taniguchi_ws/FUN-KEY/spresense/sdk/bsp/include が見つかりません。
```

確認した所，SDKに「/spresense/sdk/bsp」というフォルダは存在しませんでした．
また，[github](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense)ではv1.5.1まではbspフォルダはあり，v2.0.0以降では無くなっていました．

「spresense/sdk/bsp/include」パスは消しても大丈夫なのでしょうか？

[image: IncludePassの画面]

Answer (score 1):

私もSpresense VSCode IDEを利用しておりますが、同様のメッセージが表示されております。
SDK1.5.1まではあったようなので、昔のパスが設定されているようですね。

SDK 2.3.0を使っているのであれば消してしまっても大丈夫だと思います。
(エラーメッセージが表示されていてもTAB補完等ができているので、消さなくても大丈夫なんだとは思いますが)

お役に立てれば幸いです。